# Change BeautifulSoup URL with Try/Except Inside For Loop

Tags: python, loops, exception, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website where I will often receive an `AttributeError`. When that happens, I need to re-try the URL by adding a few leading zeroes to a list of IDs that are being looped through.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

ids = ['23135106', '37833100', '57636Q104']

base_url = "https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria="

# Create empty list to store scraped symbols
symbols = []
for id in ids:
    url = base_url + id + "&submit=Search"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    try:
        symbol = soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]').text
        print(symbol)
    except AttributeError:
        print("N/A")
    else:
        symbols.append(symbol)
```

So instead of printing `N/A` on the exception, I want to retry that `ID` by adding a leading zero (e.g., `23135106` becomes `023135106`, which is valid), and then if that fails, retry by adding two leading zeroes, etc. There will be some cases where an `ID` will fail despite how many leading zeroes are added, at which point `N/A` can be returned.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Avoid using id as a variable name,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another for-loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

IDS = ['23135106', '37833100', '57636Q104']
BASE_URL = "https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria={}&submit=Search"

def read_symbol(id):
    r = requests.get(BASE_URL.format(id))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    symbol = soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]')
    return symbol.text if symbol is not None else None

symbols = []
for id in IDS:
    for zeros in range(11):
        symbol = read_symbol(zeros * "0" + id)
        if symbol is not None:
            print(symbol)
            symbols.append(symbol)
            break
```

Comment: Thanks this gets me close, but how would I edit it so that `symbol = 'N/A'` in the case of an invalid `id` like `gdju753`?